# Authentication and authorizations in Apache Calcite (schemas, tables...)

Tags: apache-calcite

One of my customers made a proof of concept above Apache Calcite.

They want me to upgrade it, and one of the needs is to add authentication and authorization of users to restrict access to certain schemas or tables (columns as a bonus) based on user role.

I couldn't find any reference to authorization in Calcite documentation nor anywhere online, do I need to upgrade my Google-fu or is this not implemented in the Calcite project ?

Do you know of any standard way to implement this ? Ideally I would need to implement it as low as possible in the stack as I'd like to use the same authorization process for users connecting through the Avatica JDBC driver.

Currently the only "off the shelf" solution I have is to create one Calcite model per role and start one Avatica server per model, but it's not really scalable nor elegant and there has to be a better solution.

Many thanks in advance for any hint to point me in the right direction.